# Nginx returns different SSL certificates for one domain

Tags: nginx, ssl, https

Problem summary:

- one nginx server
- one domain with SSL certificate
- when accessing the site from one network, nginx returns the correct current certificate (1), and when accessing from other networks - some other one (2), expired a couple of years ago
- The old certificate (2) is missing from the server, it's not in any nginx configuration

I even tried using the grep like "**grep -r 'row_from_bad_cert' /**". For comparison, in the same way the actual current certificate (1) is found successfully, but old one (2) - none.

The server is configured 100% correctly. Problems that there could be other nginx configurations for this domain in which the certificate (2) is used are completely excluded.

At the same time, there are requests in the nginx access log in which the server issued a certificate (2).

In addition to the browser, I used utilities such as

- openssl s_client -connect *domain*:443 -prexit -debug
- nmap -p 443 --script ssl-cert *domain*

From one network, these commands return information about the current certificate (1), from another network - about the old one (2).

nmap shown correct server IP both times, but different certificates.

The site absolutely does not use technologies such as clusters, round robin dns etc. The server is the only one. DNS points to it by a single A-record.

I restart server and nginx couple of times, of course. The certificate was replaced a long time ago (the old certificate (2) was for 2021-2022).

I've set up dozens of servers, but this is the first time I've come across this situation.  I have already broken my head and exhausted all guesses.

Please, help me, maybe there are some other commands that can be used to debug a certificate request to make sure that it is exactly requested from the right server, and which certificate nginx gives when requested (i mean from server side).

Sorry, but i can't tell actual domain due to security reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems very confusing. Difficult to diagnose without configs etc.
I would break down your debugging into steps.

- Stop Nginx. Try from both networks. If your site is still responding you
  have a problem.
- Temporally remove/comment out the Nginx config for the working
  correct cert. Replace with a default "Welcome to". Try the site from both
  networks. If you are still getting the old cert when using certain networks you have some old config being referenced somewhere and you need to hunt it down. If your old cert goes away then the old   cert is still somehow linked to your new config
- Run Nginx with higher level debugging. This may point you in the
  right direction

Comment: Great thanks! You are my lifesaver. Stopping nginx helps. When accessed from some networks, the request was intercepted by an undefined proxy, from others access was direct.